# How to access a variable from another activity

Tags: java, android, logcat

So I'm trying to access a string from my main activity in my Locator activity, if I try to instantiate the String as public static it throws an error and says I cannot declare a static string in a non-static class, and when I tried to get it through intents I get an error that says.[EDIT] Now I've been able to access the intent without an error now I get a NullPointerException

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { (has extras) }
```

this is my main activity code:

```
options = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.optionselect);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        options.setAdapter(adapter);
        String XxXSelect =options.getSelectedItem().toString();
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Locator.class);
    i.putExtra("XxXchoice",XxXSelect);
    startActivity(i);
```

my locator activity code:

Line -> 204   `String XxXChoicei = getIntent().getStringExtra("XxXchoice");`

full logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.Updater(Locator.java:204)
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.clickedUpdate(Locator.java:265)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3860)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Post logcat output showing the error / stacktrace in full

Comment: @Squonk I've included the logcat.

Comment: OK so what lines are lines 204 & 265 of your Locator class?

Comment: @Squonk Ived shown line 204, line 265 and just where the method gets implemented

Comment: See my answer - it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to get rid of the `Bundle`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Locator.class);
i.putExtra("XxXchoice", XxXSelect);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the Locator class do this...

```
String XxXChoicei = getIntent().getStringExtra("XxXchoice");
```

You were complicating things by adding an exta `Bundle` to the `Intent` which already has the ability to carry a `Bundle` of its own.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the bundle and it throws the same error

Answer (score 3):

you need Static Variable to declare global variable in Application Class,

so Change your code to:

```
class GlobalClass extends Application {

  public static String myVal;

}
```

then whereever you need to access this data, get Application object by:

```
GlobalClass global=(GlobalClass)context.getApplication();
global.myVal="anything";
```

and don't forget to add it to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
        android:name="packagename.GlobalClass"
        ....
        ....
        //other codes here
</application>
```

Comment: if i do that I get either this error: `Inner class cannot have static declarations` and if i put it outside of mymain activity I cant access the findByViewId function and it throws an error.

Comment: Extending `Application` just for one `String` is completely over the top.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Youractivity.this, locator.class);
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putString("XxXchoice", XxXSelect);
 i.putExtras(b);
 startActivity(i);
```

and for more info go to [#Intent](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: That got rid of the error but not im getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`
from the line :  `String XxXChoicei = b.getString("XxXchoice");`

Comment: i've done that in both classes by writing `String XxXSelect = "";` and it still throws the error

Answer (score -1):

you can use M D answer if you want to use intent. if you want to access String from Main Activity.java you can do like this

```
in your **MainActivity**

//declare a method
public static String getString() {

   String result;        

   // assign value to string here
     result = "your assingment"

     return result;
}
```

and in your another activity

```
//get value like this

  String string = MainActivity.getString();
```

This way is used to access variable whenever required.

Comment: But then i cant get the text from my spinner because: Non-static Method findByViewId(int) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: then create a setter method and pass `String XxXSelect` to settermethod

Comment: what is a setter method?

Comment: google for getter and setter method and you will get plenty of examples. use which suits you best

Comment: @jaimin : *NEVER* create `public static` fields or methods in an Android `Activity`. Doing so can cause serious problems.

Comment: ah ok i understand what it is, but it seems a bit arduous and complicated to simply retrieve a single string

Comment: @Squonk what serious problems?? i am using this in my apps with no problem

Comment: @Squonk he asked to access variables from different class and i answered it. you cant simply downvote.

Comment: @jaimin : Fields which need initialization at `Activity` creation time, methods which need to use fields which may not be initialized, fields which need to be updated regularly by `Activity` methods when the `Activity` is not running. There is a long list. I downvoted because your answer goes against Android `Activity` design principles and in nearly 4 years I've been on Stack Overflow I've seen many problems when people do what you suggest. There are approved, stable ways of sharing data between Android Activities and using `public static` fields or methods isn't one of them.